# How to apply logarithmic type formula for speed?

Tags: mathematics, physics

I want my character's speed to ramp up using somewhat of a logarithmic formula. I am confused about how specifically I would implement this. I want the character to move fast with a little movement as as the movement gets larger the added contribution to speed is less and less. I said logarithmic function because this kind of mimics the shape of what I am after. Does anyone have an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can tell you want something like this:

```
Target_Speed = some value;
Time = -log(Initial_Speed);

while(runnning) {
    Time += delta_time;
    Current_Speed = Target_Speed - exp(-Time);

    do some other stuff
}
```

And here is why this algorithm works:

We know logarithmic function `exp(x)` tend to approach 0 when `x` goes to negative infinity. So in order to make that logarithmic function become zero we should reduce Time to a very low value, or we can increase Time, and compute `exp(-Time)` instead. based on the current argument, it's easy to see when `Time` gets very large, `-Time` becomes real large negative and so `exp(-Time)` becomes almost zero.

And for the initial values:
`Target_Speed` is your desired speed, and you can set it as you want. in the first cycle we want the `Current_Speed` to be zero, so `Target_Speed - exp(-Time)` should evaluate to zero.

```
        Target_Speed  = exp(-Time)
=>  log(Target_Speed) = log(exp(-Time)) = -Time
=> -log(Target_Speed) = Time
```

So simply by setting the initial value of Time to `-log(Target_Speed)` we will get what we wanted.

All that said I think my answer is exactly the same as Arne's except with little more information about how it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a curve and manually adjust the acceleration graph.

```
public AnimationCurve curve;
```

Then simply select it in the inspector and use a preset.
To change speed, use:

```
currentSpeed = curve.Evaluate(t);
```

where "t" can be `Time.time/5f` or other value from 0 to 1.

If you want a more physical way then use rigidbody and `rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward);`

Comment: what library is this code using?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, I thought it's a Unity question. My bad.

Answer (score -2):

each frame do this:

```
speed += 0.05;
pos += speed;
speed *= 0.99;
```

adjust parameters at will.

Comment: You should explain what this is doing and why it works in your answer.

Comment: This much I know. But I want a way to specify a smooth formula for ramping down the effect of speed as it gets faster.